# PHP save timer on exit

Tags: php, database, timer, exit, kill

I'm making a test timer which allows users to take a test based on a total timer, or an individual question timer. I need this timer to save to a database when finished to see if it was completed on time or to stop the test if time runs out. The problem is I need this to resume if the user exits in any way. Functions "register_shutdown_function()" and "pcntl_signal()" catch normal exit events, but I want to know if there is anything to catch ALL exit events, even killing the browser manually (with something like task manager) or a blue screen error, or power out, etc. Cookies would work but users switch from various stations. The only alternative I find is saving every 10 seconds (as saving every second would consume bandwidth and PC resources). Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried anything with the database already?

Comment: the database is set up, and saves correctly if used accordingly. The problem is not losing the timer if exiting the application by force or abruptly (like the examples I've mentioned)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this example, I'll be making a SQL table of the format:

```
id,session,expire
-----------------
1,d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e,1367727317
```

To build this table use:

```
CREATE TABLE `quizzes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `session` varchar(32),
  `expire` int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uc_session` (`session`)
);
```

Now for the fun part. Backend:

```
<?php
$expire_time=20; //twenty seconds
$precision=2; //how accurate the time is (lower = better, but more polls)

$db_host="127.0.0.1";
$db_user="root";
$db_pass="DATABASE_PASSWORD";
$db_db="DATABASE_NAME";

$precision_mill=$precision*1000;
$script=<<<ZZZ

<script>
    function keepAlive() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                if (xmlhttp.responseText=="expired") {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    clearInterval(minusTime);
                    document.getElementById("timeleft").innerHTML = 0;
                    alert("Quiz Expired. Please start a new one.");
                    return;
                }
                document.getElementById("timeleft").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET",document.URL+"?keepalive",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    function keepTime() {
        document.getElementById("timeleft").innerHTML-=1;
    }
    var interval=setInterval(keepAlive,$precision_mill);
    var minusTime=setInterval(keepTime,1000);
</script>

ZZZ;

if (isset($_COOKIE['session'])) {
    $mysqli=new Mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_db);
    $session=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_COOKIE['session']);
    $expire=$mysqli->query("SELECT `expire` FROM `quizzes` WHERE `session`='".$session."'");
    $expire=$expire->fetch_assoc();
    if (isset($expire['expire'])) {
        $expire=$expire['expire'];
        if (isset($_GET['keepalive'])) {
            $expire-=$precision;
            if ($expire<=0) {
                $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `quizzes` WHERE `session`='".$session."'");
                setcookie("session","",time()-3600);
                echo "expired";
                $mysqli->close();
                exit;
            }
            $mysqli->query("UPDATE `quizzes` SET `expire`=".$expire." WHERE `session`='".$session."'");
            echo $expire;
            exit;
        }
        ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php
            echo $script;
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
             echo 'Quiz resumed, you currently have <div style="display:inline" id="timeleft">'.$expire.'</div> second(s) left.';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
        <?php
        $mysqli->close();
        exit;




    } else {
        echo "Quiz expired. Please start a new one.";
        exit;
    }
} else {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST') {
        $mysqli=new Mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_db);
        $session=str_shuffle(md5(microtime()));
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `quizzes`(`session`,`expire`) VALUES('".$session."',".$expire_time.")");
        setcookie("session",$session);
        ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php
            echo $script;
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
             echo 'Quiz started, you currently have <div style="display:inline" id="timeleft">'.$expire_time.'</div> second(s) left.';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
        <?php
        $mysqli->close();
        exit;
    }
}
if (isset($_GET['keepalive'])) {
    echo "expired";
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Quiz</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="Submit" value="Start Quiz">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the user clicks start quiz, a session will be made in the database that kept track of when they first clicked start. Then, when the time passes to after the max time is allowed, the session is deleted and the quiz is stopped.

I added polling, so the if the user closes the quiz at any time, the server will keep track where they stopped and allow them to resume.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Supposing a specific scenario, let's say (in your 20 second example) the user is at 11 seconds, and there is a power out, if the next day he logs in with a different pc, how will he be able to start off at 12 seconds again? your session allows the info to save start time, but if he starts, interrupts, and starts again later?

Comment: You will need to use ajax. However, wouldn't this be prone to exploits? If the user could just 'fake' a power outage, they could extend the quiz to whatever time they need it to be.

Comment: I know it's prone to exploits, but it's what the user wants. It's only 1 question per page though so that helps. Thanks for the ajax tip, I guess there is no way to do this on pure PHP.

Comment: Check out the update, when the user closes the page, they can still resume.